# reading a file into arraylist then print out

Tags: arraylist

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emvN9.png)

I have to write a program that need to read a file into an array list then print it out by JOptionPane. however, when I used Try/Catch statement. the Catch statement had the error that I cannot fix

Answer (score 0):

I found that you have not added `System.out.print(ioe)` in your `Catch (IOException ioe)` block. Kindly add it and it will resolve the issue.

[image]

Comment: I tried to put System.out.print(ioe). but It still has that error

Comment: I tried to replicate the `try {....} catch(IOException ioe) {....}` blocks. I found that it prompts you with a message "exception IOException is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement". You will need to use "Exception e" instead of "IOException ioe". Do not forget to add `System.out.print(e)` in `catch` block. `return` statement in `catch` block is unnecessary.